# Why measure height relative to geoid instead of ellipsoid?

Tags: elevation, geoid

Why do we measure elevation relative to sea level? I understand that water settles to a level surface, but why not just measure relative to an ellipsoid and dodge all the sea level rising, geoid, and other problems. I'm looking for a real world example where height relative to a geoid is more useful than height relative to an ellipsoid. What could go wrong if I used height relative to WGS84 ellipsoid for example?

I'm new to all this and thought about it for a day but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0703/geoid1of3.html#:~:text=Because%20the%20geoid%20surface%20cannot,was%20roughly%20approximated%20by%20MSL.